# How do I get js2-mode to use spaces instead of tabs in Emacs?

Tags: javascript, emacs, ide, js2-mode

I am using [js2-mode](http://code.google.com/p/js2-mode/) to edit Javascript in Emacs, but I can't seem to get it to stop using tabs instead of spaces for indentation. My other modes work fine, just having issues w/ js2.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Do you have

```
(setq-default indent-tabs-mode nil)
```

in your .emacs? It works fine for me in emacs 23.0.60.1 when I do that. js2-mode uses the standard emacs function indent-to, which respects indent-tabs-mode, to do its indenting.

Answer (score 10):

Add this to your `.emacs` file somewhere after you load js2 mode:

```
(setq js2-mode-hook
  '(lambda () (progn
    (set-variable 'indent-tabs-mode nil))))
```

Answer (score 5):

On my copy of GNU Emacs 24.2.1, setting:

```
(setq-default indent-tabs-mode nil)
```

in .emacs is not sufficient for javascript mode, presumably because the setting is somehow being over-ridden in a per-buffer context. The following change is sufficient:

```
(custom-set-variables
 ;; custom-set-variables was added by Custom.
 ;; If you edit it by hand, you could mess it up, so be careful.
 ;; Your init file should contain only one such instance.
 ;; If there is more than one, they won't work right.
 '(indent-tabs-mode nil))
```