# Emacs default style (tab-width, offset) being overridden

Tags: variables, emacs, fedora, defaults

I am running Emacs 24.2-18 on Fedora 19 64-bit.  I have set in my `.emacs` file for the C default style to be "linux", the default tab width to be 4, the indentation to use tabs, the default C offset to be the tab width, and the Perl offset to be the tab width.  But whenever I start Emacs, the tab width and C offset are 2.  The style is listed as "linux", but when I set style in Emacs to "linux" it changes the tab width and C offset.  So the initial default style is not being loaded correctly, and I have no idea what is going on.  Here are some files of mine.  The `.emacs` is http://paste.fedoraproject.org/23068/13729669/, the contents of the `~/.emacs.d` directory are http://paste.fedoraproject.org/23070/67043137 (smartparens and archive are directories), and my installed software relating to Emacs via the Fedora software manager are:

- emacs.x86_64                      1:24.2-18.fc19                       @fedora
- emacs-auto-complete.noarch        1.3.1-5.fc19                         @fedora
- emacs-auto-complete-el.noarch     1.3.1-5.fc19                         @fedora
- emacs-common.x86_64               1:24.2-18.fc19                       @fedora
- emacs-filesystem.noarch           1:24.2-19.fc18                       @updates/18
- emacs-vala.noarch                 0.20.1-1.fc19                        @fedora
- emacs-vala-el.noarch              0.20.1-1.fc19                        @fedora

Something to note is that emacs-filesystem.noarch is a Fedora 18 package, not a Fedora 19 package.  Is there any reason for why my tab width and C offset are getting overridden like this?  I have no idea what is going on.

Comment: try [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/46174/1309352)

Comment: I do want it to use tabs.  It's just the tab width and offset not loading right that's the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The culprit is auto-indent-mode which is used in the `.emacs` file.  Auto-indent-mode will force an offset on the major mode, and the default value is 2, which you did not customize.  Because of that, it forced an offset of 2 on all your files.

Answer (score 1):

Try defining you own style, based on "linux" and overriding the offset:

```lisp
(setq-default tab-width 4
              indent-tabs-mode t)

(c-add-style "my-style"
             `("linux"
               (c-basic-offset . ,tab-width)))

(setq c-default-style "my-style")
```

Comment: I changed my `.emacs` to http://paste.fedoraproject.org/23118/72977155/ (note lines 49-57) and now tab width is correctly 4 but c-basic-offset is still 2 when I go to a C file as shown [here](http://s11.postimg.org/tr5nfibz7/emacs.png).

I changed `.emacs` to http://paste.fedoraproject.org/23119/72977435 and then the c-basic-offset is off until I manually set the style to my-style, then it works fine.  Could this be a bug in the program?

Comment: Using a hook, I've gotten it to with with C files.  It does not work, however, with in Vala files with vala-mode unless I set the variable from inside of Emacs.